# xlsx is not working in formvalidation.io?

Tags: excel, bootstrapvalidator, formvalidation.io

I am using bootstrap formvalidation plugin but i want to make validation on input type file but problem is formvaliadtion.io is not picking xlsx format but working on xls . i want to accept both formats (xls and xlsx). Here is my code:-

```
file: {
    validators: {
        file: {
            extension: 'pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,jpeg,jpg,png',
            type: 'application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,image/jpeg,image/png',
            maxSize: 2097152,   
            message: 'The selected file is not valid and it should be less than 2mb'
           }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

Formatos: **xlsx xls xlm xla xlc xlt xlw**